# Tensor product and opposite rings

Tags: proof-verification, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a ring, $M$ is a right $A$-module, and $N$ is a left $A$-module.

In this situation, we can form the tensor product, $M\otimes_A N$, and this is an abelian group (and even a $Z(A)$-module where $Z(A)$ is the center of $A$).

On the other hand, we can look at the opposite ring, and then look at
$N \otimes_{A^{op}} M$ which is a well defined abelian group (Z(A)-module).

Am I correct that the map $m\otimes n \mapsto n\otimes m$ is an isomorphism between these $Z(A)$-modules?

Is there anything missing or is this really trivial?

Comment: Yes, this is an isomorphism. I think it's not purely trivial but a very good excercise in working with tensor products. I suggest you  try to construct your isomorphism and its inverse by help of a universal property.